# Eu não consigo continuar quando selenium não encontra o XPATH

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando baixar os artigos de um website, mas quando o selenium não encontra um XPATH eu não consigo pular para o próximo. Tentei um "try" e se ele não encontrar o XPATH, coloquei um "except" para pular para o próximo, mas o código pára de rodar antes de pular para a exceção. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

```
def clica_perfil(self):
    quantidade = 0
    url = 1
    url2= url + 1
    while quantidade != 913:
        self.chrome.get('https://proceedings.science/cbee7/papers')
        sleep(1)
        try:
            self.chrome.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="hits-container"]/div/div[{url}]/div/article/a/div/h3').click()

        except:
            self.chrome.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="hits-container"]/div/div[{url2}]/div/article/a/div/h3').click()
            sleep(1)
        download = self.chrome.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,'Download').click()
        sleep(1)
        if url==1:
            self.chrome.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="edit-name"]').send_keys("c..........a@gmail.com")
            sleep(1)
            self.chrome.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="edit-pass"]').send_keys("f******a")
            sleep(1)
            self.chrome.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="edit-submit"]').click()
            sleep(1)
            self.chrome.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Download').click()
        sleep(1)

        url+=1
        if download:
            quantidade+=1
            print(quantidade)
```

Comment: qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="hits-container"]/div/div[21]/div/article/a/div/h3"}

Comment: você pode editar a pergunta para incluir as informações solicitadas, basta clicar no botão [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/540115/edit)

Answer (score -3):

Olá, tente procurar pelo Dom com o CSS_SELECTOR

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="panel-body"]')
```

Esse trecho de código vai selecionar as 20 caixas de navegação para os artigos.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).